# DateTimePicker set secondary picker minDate to first select date

Tags: jquery, datetime, momentjs, picker

I'm using the `DateTimePicker` plugin from here (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) and I have two options, one being a start date and the second being the end date.  I'm trying to set the second (end date) to the first selected date so you can't select a date prior to the first set date.  I've tried everything but can't get it working.  The code I have for the end date is:

```
$('#enddate').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: "HH:mm",
    stepHour: 1,
    stepMinute: 15,
    hourMin: 8,
    hourMax: 20,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    minDate: Date(moment($('#startdate').datepicker( 'getDate' )).format("YYYY, MM, DD")),
});
```

Which is getting the format as shown in the documentation, but each time I get the year 2021, instead of 2015 but month and day are correct!

I've used `.moment` to format the date correctly but I have no idea why it just doesn't work correctly.

Comment: use `onSelect` event on start date to set the `minDate` option for end date.

Comment: Get any solution. I have same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is revised code that works fine for me now

```
var startDateTextBox = $('#startdate');
var endDateTextBox = $('#enddate');

$.timepicker.datetimeRange(
    startDateTextBox,
    endDateTextBox,
    {
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        timeFormat: "HH:mm",
        minTime: '8:00 am',
        maxTime: '8:00 pm',
        stepHour: 1,
        stepMinute: 15,     
        range: true,        
        minDate: new Date(moment().add(1, 'days').format("YYYY, MM, DD")),
        start: {}, // start picker options
        end: {} // end picker options                   
    }
);
```